# Parallelize CouchDB View Group Indexers

Tags: parallel-processing, couchdb

I wonder if it is possible to truly parallelize the view group indexation of CouchDB with the help of multiple machines?

I guess that different indexers might by able to update different views, but is it also possible that many machines work on a single index?

How would one do that? I didn't find any statement in the replication guides or manual..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a task for [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/)'s [BigCouch](http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/).

Taken from the description of BigCouch.

> While it appears to the end-user as one [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) instance, it is in fact one or more BigCouch nodes in an elastic cluster, acting in concert to store and retrieve documents, index and serve views, and serve CouchApps.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like BigCouch really is the only solution, although its kind of sad that CouchDB doesn't support it naturally. Especially as I always thought that Map/Reduce is perfect for multi-machine parallelization.

Comment: BigCouch will be merged into CouchDB in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This was investigated in the past. The issue is that eventually, something has to operate in serial to build the B~tree in such a way that range queries across the indexed view are efficient. This is heavy additional disk activity and in the end processing the docs sequentially (on a single node) is the most effective approach, rather than copying and merging large files into a single B~tree at the end.

It does seem totally wacko the first time you realise that the highly parallelisable map-reduce algorithm is being operated sequentially, wat!

As Octavian pointed out BigCouch does this by sharding across nodes, this code will get merged into CouchDB proper this year so you can have the best of both worlds.