# How couchdb 1.6 inherently take advantage of Map reduce when it is Single Server Database

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, couchdb

I am new to couch db, while going through documentation of Couch DB1.6, i came to know that it is single server DB, so I was wondering how map reduce inherently take advantage of it.
If i need to scale this DB then do I need to put more RAID hardware, of will it work on commodity hardware like HDFS?

I came to know that couch db 2.0 planning to bring clustering feature, but could not get proper documentation on this.

Can you please help me understanding how exactly internally file get stored and accessed.
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question? It's quite confusing.. 

CouchDB allows replication therefore I would not call it a single server db - although you can run a single node and forget replication.
You can scale it without waiting for 2.0 but adding more nodes and enabling replication. I would assume you can use commodity hardware but that depends on your use cases and whole system setup.

Comment: Have a look at: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html
Might be a good source of most of the information you need as well as the first chapter: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response. Yes, Couch DB use replication as "Master-Master" only, means it stores all their file in one Server it-self. Let's assume you have 1GB file, all get saved in one couch DB server only. Then tomorrow you get 1000 GB of file then also it will get store in same DB server and then get replicated across other Couch DB Server for better performance and partition tolerance. So when you have I have increase move from 1 GB t0 1000GB then would i be required RAID machine or commodity hardware(like HDFS)? When we use to query mapreduce in single node server, what's advantage

Comment: Ok, now I get your question. Sorry, that's beyond my experience at this point. But again, maybe this will help you: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/clustering.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is something like this:

1. "MapReduce is … a parallel, distributed algorithm on a cluster." [shortened from [MapReduce article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MapReduce&oldid=715537426) on Wikipedia]
2. But CouchDB 1.x is not a clustered database.
3. So what does CouchDB mean by using the term "map reduce"?

This is a reasonable question.

The historical use of "MapReduce" as [described by Google in this paper](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) using that stylized term, and [implemented in Hadoop](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/hadoop/mapreduce/) also using that same styling implies parallel processing over a dataset that may be too large for a single machine to handle.

But that's not how CouchDB 1.x works. View index "map" and "reduce" processing happens not just on single machine, but even on a single thread! As dch (a longtime contributor to the core CouchDB project) explains in his answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725497/179583:

> The issue is that eventually, something has to operate in serial to build the B~tree in such a way that range queries across the indexed view are efficient. … It does seem totally wacko the first time you realise that the highly parallelisable map-reduce algorithm is being operated sequentially, wat!

So: what benefit does map/reduce bring to single-server CouchDB? Why were CouchDB 1.x view indexes built around it?

The benefit is that the two functions that a developer can provide for each index "map", and optionally "reduce", form very simple building blocks that are easy to reason about, at least after your indexes are designed.

What I mean is this:

With e.g. the SQL query language, you focus on what data you need — not on how much work it takes to find it. So you might have unexpected performance problems, that may or may not be solved by figuring out the right columns to add indexes on, etc.

With CouchDB, the so-called [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) approach is taken to an extreme. You have to think explicitly about how you each document or set of documents "should be" found. You say, I want to be able to find all the "employee" documents whose "supervisor" field matches a certain identifier. So now you have to write a map function:

```
function (doc) {
   if (doc.isEmployeeRecord) emit(doc.supervisor.identifier);
}
```

And then you have to query it like:

```
GET http://couchdb.local:5984/personnel/_design/my_indexes/_view/by_supervisor?key=SOME_UUID
```

In SQL you might simply say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM personnel WHERE supervisor == ?
```

So what's the advantage to the CouchDB way? Well, in the SQL case this query could be slow if you don't have an index on the supervisor column. In the CouchDB case, you can't really make an unoptimized query by accident — you always have to figure out a custom view first!

(The "reduce" function that you provide to a CouchDB view is usually used for [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Aggregate_function&oldid=701884224) purposes, like counting or averaging across multiple documents.)

If you think this is a dubious advantage, [you are not alone](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=couchdb%2C%20mongodb). Personally I found designing my own indexes via a custom "map function" and sometimes a "reduce function" to be an interesting challenge, and it did pay off in knowing the scaling costs at least of queries (not so much for replications…).

So don't think of CouchDB view so much as being "MapReduce" (in the stylized sense) but just as providing efficiently-accessible storage for the results of running `[].map(…).reduce(…)` across a set of data. Because the "map" function is applied to only a document at once, the total set of data can be bigger than fits in memory at once. Because the "reduce" function is [limited](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#reduce-and-rereduce-functions) in its size, it further encourages efficient processing of a large set of data into an efficiently-accessed index.

If you want to learn a bit more about how the indexes generated in CouchDB are stored, you might find these articles interesting:

- [The Power of B-trees](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html)
- [CouchDB's File Format is brilliantly simple and speed-efficient (at the cost of disk space).](https://plus.google.com/+rkalla/posts/CyvwRcvh4vv)
- [Technical Details, View Indexes](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Technical%20Overview#View_Indexes)

---

You may have noticed, and I am sorry, that I do not actually have a clear/solid answer of what the actual advantage and reasons were! I did not design or implement CouchDB, was only an avid user for many years.

Maybe the bigger advantage is that, in systems like Couchbase and CouchDB 2.x, the "parallel friendliness" of the map/reduce idea may come into play more. So then if you have designed an app to *work* in CouchDB 1.x it may then *scale* in the newer version without further intervention on your part.

Comment: Thanks, That was a great article and you have explained in great details.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain me, if couchdb will work on commodity hardware or will it require RAID as it is single server database and how it can be scaled further.  I have gone through this link [link](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/scaling.html)  but could not find any concrete answer.

Comment: I've used CouchDB on an EC2 t1.micro and even a Raspberry Pi Model B, so I imagine it would work on most of what you might call "commodity hardware".  If you want an easy answer: use [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) if you want scale.